# How to check that these triangles are exactly the same triangle?

Tags: expression-test

I have $6$ triangle:

```
tris = Triangle/@Permutations[{{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{0,1,1}}]
```

They are in every sense the same triangle. But how to check that these triangles are exactly the same triangle? And I note `Equal @@ tris` and `SameQ @@ tris` both cannot do this.

---

Furthermore, none of the current methods (comments and answers) seem to be able to tell if the following six triangles(`tris2`) are the same triangle:

```
Clear["`*"]
sol = Solve[{x1^2/16 + 9 y1^2 == 1, x2^2/16 + 9 y2^2 == 1, 
    x3^2/16 + 9 y3^2 == 
     1, (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 == (x1 - x3)^2 + (y1 - 
        y3)^2 == (x2 - x3)^2 + (y2 - y3)^2, (143 Sin[1/2])/1299 == 
     1/3 (y1 + y2 + y3), 572/147 Cos[1/2] == 1/3 (x1 + x2 + x3)}, {x1,
     y1, x2, y2, x3, y3}];
tris2 = Triangle[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}] /. sol
```

Comment: Hack: `Equal @@ (tris /. Triangle[x__] :> Triangle[Sort[x]])`

Comment: @Syed Check my update, thanks.

Comment: Please see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvrJS.png). I am on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: "They are in every sense the same triangle" isn't true! The orientation (normal vector) is different I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`RegionEqual`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionEqual.html).

```
RegionEqual @@ tris
(* True *)
```

If triangle coordinates are complicated symbolic expressions for which Mathematica cannot determine the equality, you can numericize them.

```
RegionEqual @@ N[tris2]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks, check my update. Maybe the `RegionEqual` have a bug.

Comment: @yode There's no bug, the expressions are just too complicated for `Equal` to check that they are actually equal. If you use `N` to get approximations you'll see `RegionEqual` works.

Answer (score 4):

We may define a helper function that calculates the length of the sides:

```
sides[tri_] := 
 Norm /@ {tri[[1, 1]] - tri[[1, 2]], tri[[1, 2]] - tri[[1, 3]], 
   tri[[1, 3]] - tri[[1, 1]]}
```

With this we may define a check function that checks for equality:

```
check[triangles_] := AllTrue[Sort /@ sides /@ N@triangles, Equal]
```

For a test:

```
check[tris]

True
```

And

```
check[tris2]

True
```

Answer (score 1):

I have voted for other answers.

Just a visualization:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2/16 + 9 y^2 - 1
cp = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -1, 1}];
```

Using `sol` from OP:

```
tr = Triangle[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}] /. sol // N;
rad = (Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2] /. sol // N)[[1]];
circ = {Red, Circle[{x1, y1}, rad]} /. sol // N;
```

The three circle intersections define a unique triangle. The  last constraints in the `Solve` provide the radius.

```
Show[cp, Graphics[{tr, circ}], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]